# How to customize Bootstrap 5 via online tool?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

For Bootstrap 3 there was a very handy [tool](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/) to customize which features you want inside the css/js minified files (in order to save loading time).

I'm reading the [manual](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/overview/) for Bootstrap 5 but honestly I don't understand how to do it. I also read the [optimize](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/optimize/) page and also here I didn't find anything useful.

Would you please help me how to keep in the minified files only the features I need?

Comment: BS5 really isn't made with a primary focus on being available as a "stand-alone" library any more; the assumption is that people will mostly be using this in more complex environments, where they have their own JS packers available to handle such tasks.

Comment: The minified Bootstrap 5 bundle (including PopperJS) is only 77kb. If you eliminate jQuery from your project (and you [usually can](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)), you can still have a slim page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [the Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/optimize/#lean-javascript) imply that a bundler is needed to load specific Bootstrap component script files, you can simply use [ES6 imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) to configure what's loaded. [Browser support](https://caniuse.com/es6-module-dynamic-import) is good.

So you wouldn't load the comprehensive dist files. You'd load a custom script that imports what you need and corresponds to the SCSS files you're using. It would look something like this:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.../popper.js/.../popper.min.js"></script>

  <script type="module">
    import '/bootstrap/main/js/dist/tooltip.js';
  </script>

  <script>
    let tooltipTriggerList = []
      .slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
    let tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function(tooltipTriggerEl) {
      return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body class="p-4">
  <p title="A tooltip." data-bs-toggle="tooltip">Hover for a Bootstrap Tooltip.</p>
</body>
```

Note that imported script files must be served with appropriate CORS headers and the MIME type `application/javascript` or you'll get errors.

Comment: Thanks, I never used this approach. I'm going to study it. If I understand correctly I won't have the complete (even minified) css/js file but rather a lot of small files on the server (i.e. `/bootstrap/main/js/dist`) so I can import (= upload) only the ones required for that specific page.

Comment: An import would be a _download_, but yeah.